# Delete object from object?

Tags: javascript, object

Given something like this:

```
function test(){
   var o = {
      // ...
      del: function(){}
   }
   return o;
}
```

Is it possible to have `.del()` remove/set to null the reference to the variable `o` such that it becomes eligible for garbage collection?

In other words, is this possible (and if so how):

```
var test1 = test();
// test1 = {...}
test1.del();
// test1 == null or test1 == undefined;
```

I did try setting `o = null` but the outside reference (`test1` would still refer to the object). I also understand that setting `test1 = null` would solve the issue, but where's the fun in that?

Comment: Try using the `delete` operator

Comment: @elclanrs: same result as setting it to null, `test1` still refers to the object.

Comment: No, it's not possible to know what variable was used to refer to an object in the call.

Comment: "*where's the fun in that?*" Why don't you like it?

Comment: @Oriol: I wanted to contain all of the *unloading/deletion* process of the object in one function, in order to reduce the likelihood that somebody (i.e me) will forget to set the value of a variable to null *in addition* to calling a deletion function.

Comment: no, you can't change the value of a caller's variable.  you could certainly delete everything _from_ `o`, and then `test1` would only be an empty object.  or with a little more finesse you could make all the methods raise an error saying that the object is no longer usable.

Comment: @Eevee: I was considering setting all the object methods to null, which would be the next best thing to do. My goal is to free as much memory as possible (this will be running in a Node server).

Comment: Just let JS garbage collect, it's what it does for a living. Or, to put it another way, can you construct a case where something you want to be and should be GC'd is not?

Comment: @torazaburo will it garbage collect if there is a reference to the object outside the function?

Comment: Yes, if there's no reference to that reference, or no refererence to that reference, or no reference to that reference, and turtles all the way up. In other words, if there's no live code which references it directly or indirectly, yes. In your case, `test1` is getting declared/set somewhere, such as in a function. So when that function goes out of scope, so will `test1`, and along with it `o`. If `test` is declared at the global scope, then sure, it will never go out of scope, but you're not doing that are you?

Comment: @JCOC611, the "reference" to that object outside of the function is a new instance. It will get cleaned up in the callers scope when its not referenced

Comment: @thebringking I'm not sure I would call it a new instance, since changes in `o` and changes in `test1` affect the same object, and are reflected on both.

Comment: @JCOC611 yeah I guess instance is not the right word, but every time test() is called, a new Object is returned, thus the pattern assumes the caller will clean up, since the Object creation is inside an in-accessible closure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see in the comments, this pattern wouldn't do what you need. You are returning a new instance of an object every time the test function is called or "newed" up. It is up to the caller of the function to clean up it's new instance of "o". On this train of thought, you shouldn't have to explicitly set a value to null or undefined to make it eligible for garbage collection. Once there are no more references to an object, it will be cleaned up for you.

Here is a great example from MDN-

```
function f(){
  var o = {};
  var o2 = {};
  o.a = o2; // o references o2
  o2.a = o; // o2 references o

  return "azerty";
}

f();
```

The internal scope of f() will be cleaned up after the function returns, since the variables inside are not "reachable" anymore. [It's called the Mark and Sweep algorithm.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Mark-and-sweep_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

No it would not be possible to have a method del() that would let an object be garbage collected. For the garbage collector to kick in, the object must be unreachable, as you had in your post `test1 = null;`

The purpose of garbage collection is so you don't have to worry about managing your memory.